# Grouping elements in inline SVG disables getElementById() on group children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have a simple SVG written directly in my HTML document. It contains one `path` with unique ID, `originalPath`. I can access that `path` directly by `getElementById()` like this:

HTML:

```
<svg id="previewImage" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <path id="originalPath" d="" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"></path>
</svg>
```

JS:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("previewImage");
var svgPath = svg.getElementById("originalPath");
// var svgPath = $("#originalPath")[0]; // Also working
```

However, if I wrap my `originalPath` in a group (directly in the HTML), the `getElementById()` function suddenly stops working, `svgPath` is `undefined`. The jQuery line doesn't work either.

```
<svg id="previewImage" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <g>        
        <path id="originalPath" d=""></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I even tried accessing the group first and then its child, but without any success. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. Something we can run i.e. a jsfiddle or a stack snippet.

Comment: Works here https://jsfiddle.net/k93f9kvr/

Comment: I was so stuck on this problem thinking it was actually the group element that caused all this trouble (without group = works well, with group = doesn't work, element suddenly undefined) that I didn't realize the problem could be somewhere else. What actually happened is that my file apparently didn't merge well in Git and I was suddenly mistakenly deleting every child of the SVG that didn't have `originalPath` ID - including the group it was wrapped in. Thank you both for your time. Can I mark this question as closed or do I need an aswer to be able to do it?